# lm in R - seemingly categorical values for continued value predictors

Tags: r, regression, lm

I am new to `R` and have a question on the `lm()` function. I have a column `Ratings` which is a continuous attribute in the range 0 to 5. When I invoke the `lm()` command as:

```
lm(some_overall_rating ~ Rating, data = Ratings)
```

I get the output like:

[image]

My question is why do I have these many co-efficients? I am ideally looking for one co-efficient for the `ratings$rating` column.

Comment: Please consult the `R` help page for `factor`.

Comment: Somewhere in your `rooms_rating` column, you have a character `NULL`. When you import the data, the column is being converted to a `factor`. You will want (probably) want to convert the `NULL`s to `NA`s (missing values) and then convert to numeric.

Comment: A little bit confused why you have `Rating` as your regressor, but output turns out to be `ratings$rooms_rating2`, `ratings$rooms_rating3`, etc. Shouldn't it be `Rating2`, `Rating3`, `Rating4`, etc? Are you sure this is the output from your code `lm(some_overall_rating ~ Rating, data = Ratings)`?

Answer (score 2):

Your ratings are being considered a `factor` variable. If you run

```
class(ratings$rooms_rating)
```

It will return `factor`. To convert to a numeric variable, try the following (depends on the `dplyr` and `readr` package).

```
ratings = ratings %>%
    mutate(rooms_rating = parse_number(rooms_rating))
```

Now, re-run your model.

Comment: Notice the `NULL` in the `lm` output. They will likely have to be dealt with first.